# Is it possible to find 4" x 8" lumber?

Tags: wood, flooring

I'm putting in an end-grain floor in my house. The idea is that you cut normal dimensional lumber into 3/4' "bricks", then lay them like tile.

What I'd like to find, however, is 4"x8" or even 4"x6", so the bricks are larger. I have not been able to find these at normal hardware stores (like Home Depot or Lowe's). Is this a specialty cut of some sort that I will need to special order?

Comment: What are you going to use to fasten them?  And how do you make sure the cuts are exactly even?

Comment: I'm going to use the same kind of glue you'd use to put down normal hardwood floor. In terms of cutting, I'll rent a big table saw from home depot, then rent a big sander after putting them all down. Here is a blog I found that explains the process: http://lumberjocks.com/thomasporter/blog/4730

Comment: Kyle - there has to be a locking mechanism (tongue/groove) or nails - and in best installs both.  Glue isn't a long-term plan unless you are planning on being very very gentle to this floor.  It is a cool idea why I asked the question.  Also note that the guy that posted the article is already having shrinkage issues.  Very cool idea though to tile the floor with wood caps but I think there needs a better plan for what to use as grout - you could ask that here.  You know this is a TON of work right?

Comment: I realize it will be lots of work, but hope the final product will be something that I will be unique and something to be proud of. I did see the mention of the grout. What I've read suggests that you should grout with a sawdust/fast-drying oil-based sealer mixture. This would allow the wood to expand and contract enough so that it won't crack.

Comment: you might be able to avoid shrinking/swelling by soaking the tiles in PEG, which is what some wood turners do. If I remember correctly, PEG is polyethylene glycol.

Comment: a local timber-frame carpenter may have cutoffs to sell cheap.

Comment: fwiw, aesthetically, i'd install them tight with no grout gap, and use feather rippings to fill in any cracks.

Comment: Aesthetically it looked OK.   I too would not install them with such a gap.  I just don't see putting this much time and effort into something that is not done intrinsically because it has so many underlying issues.  Make your own tongue and groove out of reclaimed wood or 2x12s or whatever... something that has a shelf life of more than a couple years.  Make something that people will comment on 20-50 years from now and say that is cool.  There is no way these caps can hold up more than 5 years or so.

Comment: How do you plan on preventing checking and cracking? Keeping thin bits of end-grain dimensionally stable is going to be very challenging, and much more challenging the larger the base wood.

This is why end grain floors often use very old wood that has had time to settle down--starting with wood from Home Despot is going to be very young and much more susceptible to movement. Contact a lumber yard and see if they have old stock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not lumber, but framing timber as used in post and beam construction or for center joist support.

You're looking for support beams.

Our local lumber yard carries this stock, not likely to find it at the big boxes as they're more oriented towards stick framing for housing not utility and agricultural construction.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck finding 4x8 (which is actually 3.5x8) at lumber recycling operations.  And it is impressively inexpensive at such places.  For example, if you are near Portland, Oregon, [The Rebuilding Center](http://rebuildingcenter.org/).  The disadvantage is that they don't regularly have anything, let alone everything.  Inventory is subject to what has been brought in recently.

Answer (score 0):

The MacLachlan Woodworking Museum in Kingston Ontario laid this amazing floor in 2009 (or prior):

[image]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MR181yRJPs

and here:

[image: http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/oExzIWWDvaU/mqdefault.jpg]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oExzIWWDvaU

and here:

[image]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0maJWFjoGbM

Comment: Neat! Basically Terrazzo in wood.

Comment: It's been down for almost 5 years now.  I wonder how it has held up. I'm also curious how the kept the disks from checking. My guess is that they were soaked in PEG before hand. I thought the tape was a good idea: after doing the layout, put a piece of tape on each disk on the topside (good side) so that **a)** when you pick it up you don't forget which side to put the adhesive on, **b)** you know the orientation for putting it back down, and **c)** then remove the tape so that you know which are already adhered.